# user controls VB2010 express

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, composite-controls

I am creating an application, which displays data from 4 or more stations. The data to be displayed is text and it can have variable number of sub-stations in it. So I plan to create 2 levels of User controls. UserControl1 for displaying the sub-station data, which is collection of Text Boxes in a row. The number of TextBoxes for a sub-staion is fixed. The second user control,UserControl2, for a Station consists of multiple UserControls1 added to it during run time and other data.

I am creating the application in VB2010 Express edition tool. I have written the code but when I try to run it, Usercontrol 1 fails to load. So is this type of embedding user controls possible ?

Comment: A test container for UserControl1 opens and it asks me to select the userControl to load. When I select the user control, it does nothing.

Comment: Yes it can be done. The error I was receiving was due to incorrect parent initialization of the form.